# Unable to locate credentials - accessing AWS secret manager with Python on ubuntu

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have ec2 with an IAM role assigned. The role has explicit policy to read secret manager values. However, when I try to connect on ec2 using

```
session = boto3.session.Session()
client = session.client(service_name='secretsmanager',region_name='x')
secret = client.get_secret_value(SecretId='x')
```

I get the error 'Unable to locate credentials'. What am I doing wrong? I thought that as long as the role has a policy that allows reading from AWS, I don't need to store the aws secret id, etc. on ec2/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you still have to configure it to use that specific role from the SDK.

Useful Link:
[AWS Configure QuickStart](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html)

Here is an AWS Python Example for what you are doing:

[AWS Python Example](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/secrets-manager.html)

Comment: hm, I thought I could get rid of storing any keys, secrets, etc on ec2

Comment: You do not store the key, you have to still configure the environment variables to know which role to use

Comment: boto3 utilize the /.aws/credentials files to know which role to assume and properly execute API comamnds

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html

Go to IAM Section